# Whether to worry about a potential memory-leak or not

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, memory-leaks

I'm building a [library for AngularJS](https://github.com/maurei/angular-table-editor) that aims at transforming a HTML-table into an excel-like sheet. I've been worrying about performance and I've been running some tests, and I'm curious whether the following profile is something I need to worry about or not. See the memory profile below. [image: Profile]

To get this profile, I'm "scrolling" through the table rows ([see the basic example](https://maurei.github.io/angular-table-editor/#!/basic), click on the top row, push and hold arrow down key). The example contains 5 rows, whereas the graph was produced with a much longer list: 300 rows. After scrolling to the middle of the list I would pause, force a garbage collection, and continue scrolling towards the end.

In a nutshell, every time you move down to the next row, a bunch of input elements are created and some AngularJS stuff (a new scope, some watchers) is being connected to them. The opposite is done for the row that is being transformed back into an ordinary table row element (should be, of course if something is leaking, its probably in here)

With respect to memory: I guess, intuitively, it should make sense that, given it is well implemented, memory related to transforming a `tr` element into the editable row state should be freed once that row is transformed back into its original state (that is: the static `tr` state)

Analysing the graph, there's two things that grab my attention.

- You can clearly see a climbing saw-tooth pattern which [a strong indicator for a memory leak](http://www.dwmkerr.com/fixing-memory-leaks-in-angularjs-applications/#identifyingmemoryleaks). A bunch of stuff is being freed, but not all. => stuff is leaking when transitioning through the table rows
- However, when forcefully doing a GC, everything is gone. So it's not a memory leak after all, because if it were, it wouldn't be gone at this point. Note: afaik I can't easily analyse what is accumulating during the saw-tooth phase because doing a snapshot forces a GC, which apparently clears everything as we can see here.

Thus my questions:

- Since a forced GC cleans it up it is not a leak (?). But intuitively seen it should be freed after row transition: is it chrome doing complex stuff under the hood, or does it hint at bad code (can I rewrite stuff to promote a more complete GC after each transition?)
- Should I even worry about everything that is rising during saw-tooth phase as it is cleaned after a forced GC anyway?

**[edit]**
If you want to check out the code, you can do so [here](https://github.com/maurei/angular-table-editor/tree/master/src). Most of the meat is in

- table-editor-cell.directive.js
- table-editor-row.directive.js
- table-editor.directive.js

Comment: I'm not that well versed in the inner workings of V8, but the graph you are showing reminds me of a poorly written datastructure or DOM interaction. Are you perhaps inserting allot of elements into the DOM without removing them?

Comment: It's not the heap I would worry about, but more the listeners.  That's not going down at all.  I've a feeling you have attached your listeners too high up the DOM..  But without seeing any code it's hard to tell.

Comment: @Keith Actually, you're more than welcome to take a look [at my code](https://github.com/maurei/angular-table-editor/tree/master/src). I would be grateful. The [te-cell directive](https://github.com/maurei/angular-table-editor/blob/master/src/table-editor-cell.directive.js), [te-row directive](https://github.com/maurei/angular-table-editor/blob/master/src/table-editor-row.directive.js) and [table-editor directive](https://github.com/maurei/angular-table-editor/blob/master/src/table-editor.directive.js) is where the meat is at

Comment: angularjs is not my thing, but looking at the code -. `$(window).on('click',` I can't find any `off` for this, does is it  get called multiple-times?,.. `element.on('click'  & element.on("keydown"`  does the element get de-referenced during your scroll.  IOW: I would try looking into when & if these listeners get removed.

Comment: @Keith I had thought about this before. Long AngularJS-under-the-hood story short: the `constructor` and `link` function are called just once per HTML table (see for yourself by adding a breakpoint over there in debugger), so shouldn't be the problem. The thing boils down to this  however: in order to analyse memory/listeners I should take a snapshot, [which triggers a GC just before that](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/heap-snapshots) => its gone. I.e.: its gone with a GC, so is it really a leak? Seems that the GC is just not (fully) triggered